# Using Bootstraps Input Field Style with JQuery Functionalities

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm using **Bootstrap** and **JQuery UI** and i seem to have stumbled upon a problem. I styled most of my code in Bootstrap. I was trying to implement a age validation dialog-box "**Validation**: if a person is less then 18 years of age do something...". I managed to implement that age-checking validation with JQuery. Next, I wanted to make the input-field look like bootstraps input fields, because all of my input-fields in my main form look like the bootstraps input-field. How can i accomplish this?

```js
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#age").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(value, ui) {
                var current = new Date().getTime(), 
                    dateSelect = new Date(value).getTime();
                    age = current - dateSelect;
                    ageGet = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
                if(ageGet < 18){
                    less_than_18(ageGet);
                }
            },
            yearRange: '1900:+0d',//base year:current year
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: '-18yr',
        }).attr("readonly", "readonly"); //prevent manual changes


        function less_than_18(theAge){
          $( function() {
            $('<div></div>').dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: "Age Check?",
              open: function () {
                var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
                $(this).html(markup);
              },
              buttons: {
                'Confirm': function() {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Change': function() {
                   $('#age').val('');
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                }
              }
            });
          } );  
        }

    });
```

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select your age" id="age">
     
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or a snippet of your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have both the look of bootstrap and functionality of the date-picker from JQuery-UI I had to rearrange my reference around.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#age").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(value, ui) {
                var current = new Date().getTime(), 
                    dateSelect = new Date(value).getTime();
                    age = current - dateSelect;
                    ageGet = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
                if(ageGet < 18){
                    less_than_18(ageGet);
                }
            },
            yearRange: '1900:+0d',//base year:current year
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: '-18yr',
        }).attr("readonly", "readonly"); //prevent manual changes


        function less_than_18(theAge){
          $( function() {
            $('<div></div>').dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: "Age Check?",
              open: function () {
                var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
                $(this).html(markup);
              },
              buttons: {
                'Confirm': function() {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Change': function() {
                   $('#age').val('');
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                }
              }
            });
          } );  
        }

    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select your age" id="age">
     
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get rid of the jquery UI css and any associated files. 
Check out my **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/t0g653f0/)**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select your age" id="age">
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way i want it. This removed JQuery's validation functionalities. If you take out  `<div class="container">` and `<div class="form-group">` And take out the bootstrap style and scripts.  You will see the functionalities i'm talking about.

Comment: @taji01 I see what you mean. Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/hvL5zc0y/ . This does not implement your functionality entirely but it may get you closer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Head:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#age").datepicker({
            onSelect: function (value, ui) {
                var current = new Date().getTime(),
                        dateSelect = new Date(value).getTime();
                age = current - dateSelect;
                ageGet = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
                if (ageGet < 18) {
                    less_than_18(ageGet);
                }
            },
            yearRange: '1900:+0d', //base year:current year
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: '-18yr',
        }).attr("readonly", "readonly"); //prevent manual changes


        function less_than_18(theAge) {
            $(function () {
                $('<div></div>').dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: "Age Check?",
                    open: function () {
                        var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
                        $(this).html(markup);
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        'Confirm': function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        'Change': function () {
                            $('#age').val('');
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Inside Body:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">Age</div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select your age" id="age">
                </div>

            </div> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the styling from bootstrap form elements, then you can add a custom class to your `input` and overwrite all its css properties and make it same as bootstrap form components.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#age").datepicker({
            onSelect: function(value, ui) {
                var current = new Date().getTime(), 
                    dateSelect = new Date(value).getTime();
                    age = current - dateSelect;
                    ageGet = Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25); // age / ms / sec / min / hour / days in a year
                if(ageGet < 18){
                    less_than_18(ageGet);
                }
            },
            yearRange: '1900:+0d',//base year:current year
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            defaultDate: '-18yr',
        }).attr("readonly", "readonly"); //prevent manual changes


        function less_than_18(theAge){
          $( function() {
            $('<div></div>').dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: "Age Check?",
              open: function () {
                var markup = 'Applicant is not 18 years old. Do you wish to continue?';
                $(this).html(markup);
              },
              buttons: {
                'Confirm': function() {
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Change': function() {
                   $('#age').val('');
                   $(this).dialog('close');
                }
              }
            });
          } );  
        }

    });
```

```css
.ageValidation{
display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
     transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">

     <input type="text" class="form-control ageValidation" placeholder="Select your age" id="age">
     
        </div> 
    </div>
```